# JSON_PRETTY_PRINT works on localhost but doesnt work on server

Tags: php, json

On localhost xamp, it prints fine. But same script, when i uploaded it on server (cpanel hostgator php7) it stays without formatting.

Here is my code, data are same and fine. Chrome and not "View page source". Php7.3 on hosting, php 8 on localhost, no errors

```
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
echo(json_encode($data,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES) );
```

Heres screenshot on hosting and on localhost

[image]

Comment: To me that makes no sense. How are you looking at the output? In the browser? In the source code of the browser? Using the developer tools? And which browser are you using? (different browsers handle json content differently)

Comment: Same browser - chrome, localhost formated it, on server doesnt

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I asked multiple questions, so it makes sense you only answered the last one. Could you now address this one: "How are you looking at the output?" The options I could think of were: "In the browser? In the source code of the browser? Using the developer tools?".

Comment: To me it does not look like your server is sending the content-type header correctly. You can confirm that this is the case yourself when the browser uses the monospaced font locally (which is to indicate that chrome determined that it is showing some sort of code) and it is using the default web font on the server. You can also confirm this by looking at the response header. Now the why (given the information provided here) can be anyone's guess

Comment: This might be a [headers already send](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php/8028987#8028987) error.

Comment: No errors at all. No blank, white spaces

Comment: Do not add solved to your question. Solutions go in the answer space below

Answer (score 0):

I assume the code in your question is incomplete because there's a lot more code that you left out. I would suggest to make a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), to check your findings. Something like this:

```
<?php

$data = ['row1' => 'content1',
         'row2' => 'content2',
         'row3' => 'content3'];

header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
echo json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
```

Put that in a `test.php` file and run it both locally and on the server.

In Chrome use "View page source" to check the result.

My guess is that there's no difference in the output. This would mean that the problem is somewhere else in your code.

Comment: your code -> not formatted on hosting, but formatted on localhost.

Comment: @erikparker And you're actually using "View page source"?

Comment: of course not view page source. If i view page source, why would i even need json_pretty_print

Comment: @erikparker You try it to find the root cause of your problem. If the source code looks the same in both cases, but the formatted output doesn't, then that does tell us something.

Comment: yes, source is same - formatted on both. Only visible results are not formatted part from JSON_PRETTY_PRINT  not working

Comment: If both source codes are the same then `JSON_PRETTY_PRINT` is working. It is not the problem. I think that _apokryfos_ is on to something. It might be a header issue.